# Кнопка button текст на кнопке

Tags: java, android

Как на кнопке button изменить стиль  текста ( к примеру подчеркнуть , сделать жирным), через MainActivity?

Answer (score 4):

У кнопки есть свойство `android:textStyle="bold"` для жирного текста , так же там и другие есть

Если через код , то `button.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);`

Насчет прдчеркиваний уже сложнее ..  [Как то так](http://habrahabr.ru/post/167343/)

```
 SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Button");
 text.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 button.setText(text);
```

Таким способом можно стилизовать текст в широких пределах (в том числе только части надписи):подчеркивания,зачеркивания,наклон,разый цвет для разных участков и тп. Подробности по ссылке выше.